# Android: Stuck on ClassCastException using getApplication(), trying to integrate Facebook Friendpicker sample

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook, sample

I'm trying to integrate the Facebook Friendpicker Sample into the Parse.com quickstart code. This would create an app that logs in through Facebook, is connected to Parse.com and allows you to pick friends (all part of a greater plan, ofcourse). After selecting facebook friends you can click "done", at which point the app would store the selected friends into the application. When clicking "done" it crashes instead (but only after clicking "done", the selection screen itself works fine). Could you help me understand what is going wrong (why the following line causes a problem)?

The line that is causing the problem is: GamePlannerFriendPickerApplication application = (GamePlannerFriendPickerApplication) getApplication();

The LogCat:

```
    06-02 15:25:02.176: W/dalvikvm(274): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
    06-02 15:25:02.285: E/AndroidRuntime(274): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    06-02 15:25:02.285: E/AndroidRuntime(274): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.parse.integratingfacebooktutorial.IntegratingFacebookTutorialApplication
    06-02 15:25:02.285: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.parse.integratingfacebooktutorial.GamePlannerPickFriendsActivity$2.onDoneButtonClicked(GamePlannerPickFriendsActivity.java:66)
    06-02 15:25:02.285: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment$6.onClick(PickerFragment.java:650)
    06-02 15:25:02.285: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
    06-02 15:25:02.285: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
    06-02 15:25:02.285: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    06-02 15:25:02.285: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    06-02 15:25:02.285: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    06-02 15:25:02.285: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    06-02 15:25:02.285: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-02 15:25:02.285: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    06-02 15:25:02.285: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    06-02 15:25:02.285: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    06-02 15:25:02.285: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The annoying thing is that the facebook example uses the exact same method (line 80, PickFriendsActivity.java), only with different variable names.

See friendPickerFragment.setOnDoneButtonClickedListener in GamePlannerPickFriendsActivity.java:

```
    public class GamePlannerPickFriendsActivity extends FragmentActivity {
FriendPickerFragment friendPickerFragment;

// A helper to simplify life for callers who want to populate a Bundle with the necessary
// parameters. A more sophisticated Activity might define its own set of parameters; our needs
// are simple, so we just populate what we want to pass to the FriendPickerFragment.
public static void populateParameters(Intent intent, String userId, boolean multiSelect, boolean showTitleBar) {
    intent.putExtra(FriendPickerFragment.USER_ID_BUNDLE_KEY, userId);
    intent.putExtra(FriendPickerFragment.MULTI_SELECT_BUNDLE_KEY, multiSelect);
    intent.putExtra(FriendPickerFragment.SHOW_TITLE_BAR_BUNDLE_KEY, showTitleBar);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_planner_pick_friends_activity);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // First time through, we create our fragment programmatically.
        final Bundle args = getIntent().getExtras();
        friendPickerFragment = new FriendPickerFragment(args);
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.friend_picker_fragment, friendPickerFragment)
                .commit();
    } else {
        // Subsequent times, our fragment is recreated by the framework and already has saved and
        // restored its state, so we don't need to specify args again. (In fact, this might be
        // incorrect if the fragment was modified programmatically since it was created.)
        friendPickerFragment = (FriendPickerFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.friend_picker_fragment);
    } 

    friendPickerFragment.setOnErrorListener(new PickerFragment.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onError(PickerFragment<?> fragment, FacebookException error) {
            GamePlannerPickFriendsActivity.this.onError(error);
        }
    });

    friendPickerFragment.setOnDoneButtonClickedListener(new PickerFragment.OnDoneButtonClickedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDoneButtonClicked(PickerFragment<?> fragment) {
            // We just store our selection in the Application for other activities to look at.
            GamePlannerFriendPickerApplication application = (GamePlannerFriendPickerApplication) getApplication();
            application.setSelectedUsers(friendPickerFragment.getSelection());

            setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
            finish();
        }
    });
}

private void onError(Exception error) {
    String text = getString(R.string.exception, error.getMessage());
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    try {
        GamePlannerFriendPickerApplication application = (GamePlannerFriendPickerApplication) getApplication();
        List<GraphUser> selectedUsers = application.getSelectedUsers();
        if (selectedUsers != null && !selectedUsers.isEmpty()) {
            friendPickerFragment.setSelection(selectedUsers);
        }
        // Load data, unless a query has already taken place.
        friendPickerFragment.loadData(false);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        onError(ex);
    }
}
    }
```

I'll also include the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.parse.integratingfacebooktutorial"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".IntegratingFacebookTutorialApplication" >
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name=".UserDetailsActivity" 
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>

    <activity android:name=".GamePlannerPickFriendsActivity"
              android:label="Pick Friends">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".GamePlannerFriendPickerApplication"
              android:label="@string/app_name"/>
    <activity android:name=".GamePlannerPickFriendsMainCode"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" 
        android:value="@string/app_id"/>
</application>
```

And, just to be safe, the GamePlannerFriendPickerApplication.java

```
    public class GamePlannerFriendPickerApplication extends Application {
private List<GraphUser> selectedUsers;

public List<GraphUser> getSelectedUsers() {
    return selectedUsers;
}

public void setSelectedUsers(List<GraphUser> selectedUsers) {
    this.selectedUsers = selectedUsers;
}
}
```

I really hope you can help me out. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here (still learning the ropes), so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: i am having the trouble with the friendpicker sample provided along with the facebook sdk,It is not retreiving any friends at all,Only shows a white screen.Please help if you can resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your application manifest tag as follows:

```
<application
        android:name="full.package.name.GamePlannerFriendPickerApplication"
```

In your manifest right now you are declaring the class "IntegratingFacebookTutorialApplication", so when you get an application reference and try to cast it to your GamePlannerFriendPickerApplication is throwing the exception, because the instance is of type "IntegratingFacebookTutorialApplication", just make sure to set the proper Application name (GamePlannerFriendPickerApplication) and your class cast exception should be gone...

Regards!